# Python - list index out or range (unicode)

Tags: python, arrays, unicode

I am writing a program to encrypt / decrypt an inputted message using a key generated from a pool

The pool is created by appending unicode characters to an array

When selecting option 2 (encrypt) and reading the genkey.txt file (after generating the key with option 1), the program shows an index error as shown:

> Exception has occurred: IndexError
> list index out of range, line 58, in b = keyarray[a]

However, when removing the unicode script and replacing the pool with plain text (e.g [a, b, c...]) the message is encrypted without any issue.

Any way to fix this?

Code:

```
import random

programrun = 0
encryptedarray = []
decryptedarray = []
keyarray = []
while programrun < 1:
    pool = []
    for i in range(32,123): #Unicode characters
        pool.append(chr(i))
    print("Encryption / Decryption")
    print("")
    print("1. Generate Key")
    print("2. Encrypt")
    print("3. Decrypt")
    print("4. Quit")
    print("NOTE: Key must be generated before selecting Encryption / Decryption")
    print("")
    
    option = int(input("Enter the number corresponding to the option: "))
    if option == 1:
        a = 20
        while a > 0:
            b = random.randint(0,57)
            c = pool[b]
            keyarray.append(c)
            a = a - 1
        keygen = ("".join(keyarray))
        print("Your generated key is:", keygen)
        print("")
        print("(Make sure you have generated a key before typing 'yes')")
        writebool = input("Do you want to save the file to your computer? ")
        if writebool == "yes":
            keyfile = open("genkey.txt", "x")
            keyfile.write(keygen)
            keyfile.close()
            wbval = 1
            print("File saved to genkey.txt successfully")
            print("")
            quitval = 1
        elif writebool == "no":
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("Type yes or no")
    
    elif option == 2:
        encryptvalid = 0
        while encryptvalid < 1:
            msg = str(input("Enter the message to be encrypted: "))
            genkeyf = open("genkey.txt", "r")
            genkeydata = genkeyf.read()
            if genkeydata == keygen:
                print("File VALID")
                encryptvalid = 1
                for i in msg:
                    a = pool.index(i)
                    b = keyarray[a]
                    encryptedarray.append(b)
                p = ("".join(encryptedarray))
                print("")
                print("Your encrypted string is: ")
                print("".join(encryptedarray))
            else:
                print("File INVALID")
                print("Please check if the genkey.txt file matches the current generated key.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`a = pool.index(i)` looks up the index of a character of the message in the pool, then that index is used to lookup a value in the keyarray with `b = keyarray[a]`.

`pool` is 91 bytes long, but `keyarray` is 20 bytes long, so many of the indexes are too high.  You probably want `b = keyarray[a % len(keyarray)]`.  This uses the modulus operator to constrain the lookup from 0-19.